# Skype Script For Contacting Me On Skype

Tags: javascript

I would like a link on my website that when somebody clicks on it, it either starts a chat with me on skype, or if I'm offline, it starts a chat with my friend and when he's offline, it sends a pop-up saying "Sorry, nobody is availible." The status has to be online, otherwise go to the next person.

I found this, which outputs a number that corresponds to the status. If the number is anything else then 2, go to the next person or if it was the last person, pop-up.

http://mystatus.skype.com/username.num

This is the code that has to be performed in order to start the chat:

"skype:username?chat"

Comment: You idea isn't solvable in pure javascript, because the same origin policy wont let you read the status from another domain. You have to setup a reverse proxy or implement it in a server side language.

Comment: Stack overflow is not some service that codes stuff for you for free.  You have to try something, and, if you are having problems with what you have tried, we will help you there.

Comment: I tried, but I got stuck, and now I see the comment of SFX, I'll stop trying.

Comment: what do you guys ask for such a script then?

Comment: And where did you get stuck? Did you get the status?

Comment: @user1692987 - You've clearly done a bit of the leg work, but I take it you're not a programmer, or planning to learn to program? If that's the case, see if a friend will help... otherwise you might have to cough up some cash and pay someone to do it for you.

If you are a programmer (or learning to program), could you fill us in on how far you got with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written that for you.:

```
var user1 = "Your Username";
var user2 = "Friend's Username";
$.ajax({
  url: "http://mystatus.skype.com/" + user1 + ".num",
  cache: false
}).done(function( num ) {
  if(num == 2) {
    document.write('<a href="skype:"' + user1 + '"?chat"> Chat With User1 </a>');
  }else {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://mystatus.skype.com/" + user2 + ".num",
        cache: false
    }).done(function( num2 ) {
        if(num2 == 2){
            document.write('<a href="skype:"' + user2 + '"?chat"> Chat With User2 </a>');
        } else {
            //Open Pop-up
            alert("Sorry, No one available to chat now. Try again later.");
        }
    });
  }
});
```

It is written with jQuery plugin and AJAX..

Comment: @user1692987 The code had some mistakes. I have edited it. anyway You're welcome... but I have checked the My Status service with my skype username, but It doesn't seem to provide right statuses.. I'm online, but it shows me offline.. The same is happening with my friend also

Comment: @MiroMarkarian There's a reason we don't give out code. Not only did OP learn nothing, he's more likely to ask another poor question ([How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)) because somebody will just do the work for him.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian Go to your privacy settings on skype and change "Web Status" to true. Many Thanks!

Comment: @MiroMarkarian - great effort, although sachleen does have a point. One has to be careful, since a great answer can occasionally get downvotes this way! Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: @halfer I do agree with sachleen.. But I have only wrote some ajax and if to show what to do.. I haven't wrote that much of code to be considered as full-code or full-script.